# dynamic radio button generation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From this json array I need to build dynamic radio buttons with mobile numbers in `angularjs`:

```
challengeSelectInfo:
[
    {"mob_0" : "xxxxx1211"},
    {"mob_1" : "xxxxx1211"},
    {"mob_2" : "xxxxx1211"}
]
```

I tried `ng-repeat` and iterate over `challengeSelectInfo` but the issue that I'm facing is `keys(mob_0,mob_1,mob_2)` are different and I'm unable to generate dynamic radio buttons.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify keys for your arrays :

```
$scope.newArr = [];
angular.forEach(challengeSelectInfo, function(val, key) {
    /* do something for all key: value pairs */
     $scope.newArr.push({id: key, value: val});
});
```

Then loop through newArr arrays and assign to radio button :

```
<input name="{{item.value}}" type="radio" ng-model="item.id" value="{{item.value}}">
```

Comment: hi, thanks. can you give me a working js fiddle for the same. like what I need to put as key and value. sorry for silly questions

Answer (score 0):

made this simply for your understanding purpose hope you can achieve your requirement by using this

```js
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.challengeSelectInfo= [
    {"mob_0" : "xxxxx1211"},

{"mob_1" : "xxxxx1211"},

{"mob_2" : "xxxxx1211"} ];


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in challengeSelectInfo ">
     <div ng-repeat="(x,y) in v">
      <input type="radio" />{{y}}
     </div>
   </div>
   </body>
  

</html>
```

Comment: after using this m getting ng-repeat:dupes error :(

Comment: use track by  $index option in ng-repeat

Comment: thanks. track by $index is working but it's giving entire challengeSelectInfo data as one one radio button. for every spaces, commas everything it gives a radio button. how to rectify that?

Comment: can u give me a plunker with currently what your seeing in output.....and to resolve this you need to track it  by a unique property like keys here.....

Comment: hey, m sorry I can't provide what output m getting as my codebase is in virtual machine. you just let me know {{y}}, here what to write and how to track it by a unique properties. m totally new to this.

Comment: try this in second ng-repeat <div ng-repeat="(x,y) in v track by x ">

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this  [JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2330/)

```
  var data = {  "challengeSelectInfo" : [ {"mob_0" : "xxxxx1211"},
   {"mob_1" : "xxxxx1211"}, {"mob_2" : "xxxxx1211"} ]}
  $scope.radioGrp = (data['challengeSelectInfo'] || []).map(function(obj){      
       for(var i in obj){ 
          return { 'value': i, 'name': obj[i] }; 
       } 
     });

 <input type="radio" ng-repeat="rb in radioGrp" ng-value="rb.value" ng-modal="radioValue" name="{{rb.name}}">
```